# Tricky MySQL batch query

Tags: php, mysql, performance, batch-processing

I have a database of events which gets updated every night.  A single event has information across three (or more) tables.  Recently the volume of updates has caused my MySQL engine to be very slow to the point that my other queries get frozen while new events are being inserted.  In order to speed things up I want to make a series of batch queries instead of having to do each one separately which I feel like is a large part of the overhead.

The problem is because the data is spread across several tables this is what I have to do to insert a single event:

```
   (in Mysql) INSERT INTO 'locations' (...) VALUES (...) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE ...
   (in php get the last inserted id into variable $locationID)
   (in Mysql) INSERT INTO 'event_info' (...) VALUES ($locationID, ...) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE...
   (in php get the last inserted id into variable $eventID)
   (in Mysql) INSERT INTO 'event_times' (...) VALUES ($eventID, ...) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE...
```

I'm not looking for help in designing the tables, but as you can see to insert a single event requires at least three inserts *each of which depends on getting the id from the previous one.*  This is why I didn't know where to begin for making this into a batch request.  Any help for designing this process into a batch request would be awesome, thanks!

**EDIT:**  I might already have the location or the event info previously and that is why the ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE part is there so that if it was already in the database I get the old id.  I don't know until the insert if it is new data or if it already exists in the database. (because of that unless I am misunderstanding, I can't do things that preallocate the ids since this assume a new id every time.)

Comment: What database engine are you using? Keep in mind that MyISAM locks table for every insert.

Comment: It is MyISAM but the other queries that were getting frozen were going to a completely different table than the ones that this would affect so I think it was just the overall strain of all the inserts and index updates.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't use auto incrementing columns - preallocate your reference id's before inserting. That way you can use a bulk insert and remove the dependency.

Update:

1. Select any existing id's out of the database (ideally a single select for all known data).
2. Enrich data to insert with any known id's. ( calculate a key for each item, which would correspond with the primary key for your table in the database, use that to update the item with the id from the database ) - you want to ultimately split the data into items which you know about in the database, and thus have an known id - and data which doesn't exist in the database, and thus needs a key allocating. I'm assuming your table has a primary key which isn't just the id - otherwise how else would the database know you already have the data in the database.
3. Allocate new id's to any records without an id.
4. bulk replace data in the database ( inserting multiple lines with a single statement ).

Comment: Interesting, how would I do that?  The thing is that the location could be one I already have and until the ON DUPLICATED KEY UPDATE part happens I don't know if it was  new or not...

Comment: Change your INSERT INTO, to REPLACE INTO - then it will automatically update when your primary key matches.

Comment: As for your id's - create your self a method of allocating unique references outside of mysql.

Comment: Thanks didn't know about that feature.  SO I should have them all as REPLACE INTO and then put all of those into a batch?  Is there any way to do all the location inserts first, all the info inserts second, and all the time inserts third?

Comment: Awesome, ok I see the solution now.  Thanks!

Comment: @MikeChamberlain hmm `REPLACE` won't work if hackartist would use sequences for primary keys. If, on the other hand, he's going to check for existence of record prior to doing `INSERT`, then `REPLACE` has no difference from `ON DUPLICATED KEY UPDATE`.

Comment: I just realized that what about the other events which have reference to the old IDs?  If I just get a new ID without replacing all the old ones then I will have orphaned data...

Comment: Hmm, can you query the database for existing id's, enrich your data to insert, fill in any blanks with new id's, then do the insert? - then you can still do the bulk insert.

Comment: I'm afraid that might create as much overhead as is already done... my whole goal was to reduce the amount of stress on the DB but I will have to test to see.

Comment: replacing the insert with a bulk insert should ultimately be a big win, as mysql updates the indexes after each complete insert statement. You also benefit from the reduced roundtrip time of 1 transaction over N transactions. The preselect if properly indexed shouldn't be huge - and you can pull back all the required information with one query ideally.

Comment: Can you edit your original answer to have the steps you are suggesting then?  Is it Select to get all the IDs of the locations, etc. or is it for each event select, then replace into and update the other tables?

Comment: What does the second step mean? Also when I select the ids out of the database I somehow have to keep track of which one gets which new id right?  (Sorry I am not getting this but I have to actually program it later so I want to be 100% sure I understand)

Comment: AH, ok so I have to do most of the work in the php, so I have some big array and store the ID which I intend to use there so that I can do a single insert for all the locations, all the event infos, and all the event times.  Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2):

Don't know about details MySQL, but any self-respecting RDBMS has so-called "sequence" entities which are meant to be used as source of unique values suitable for tables' primary keys.

Below is approach to solve your problem using sequences, the one I encountered multiple times. Using pseudo-code:

1. Start transaction
2. Select 3 next values from some sequence. Again, any self-respecting RDBMS will guarantee that every query for "next value of sequence" will return unique value, suitable to be used as a primary key. Three selected values will be for primary keys of new records in `locations`, `event_info`, `event_times`;
3. Perform `INSERT INTO locations` using value from 1st step;
4. Perform `INSERT INTO event_info` using values from 1st step;
5. Perform `INSERT INTO event_times` using values from 1st step;
6. `COMMIT` transaction, if all was well. Otherwise, `ROLLBACK` transaction.

It's essential to make all `INSERT`s in one transaction.
For further enhancements, you can batch your queries.

**UPDATE** To comply with your requirement about possible pre-existence of data prior to `INSERT`s

If your incoming updates are always contain whole set of data: that is location, event_info and event_times: Then use above approach and just delete old instances of records in tables. This assumes that you can `SELECT` old instances using some data other than primary key (that's data called domain-level primary key). Don't forget to make `DELETE` in the same transaction!

Comment: How can I do this with the problem I mentioned just now in the EDIT to my original question?

Comment: Thanks, I voted your answer up. The other answer suggested a few minutes ago I use REPLACE INTO which will do the delete and insert for me, but if he hadn't answered first I would have accepted your answer.  Thanks.

Comment: On second thought, I might have to do it this way, because simply replacing will change the IDs which the other tables already have... I wish there were a way without having to change those IDs... your method would also have me DELETE the old records which other data in the other tables could still point to right?

Comment: Use of Transactions speeds up bulk updating.  Final disk writes are held up till the COMMIT.

Comment: @hackartist you must delete old records, right. I assumed there are no other tables besides three tables mentioned. If there are other tables which reference some of `locations`, `event_info` or `event_times`, you'll need to update them as well.