# Tricky MySQL Batch Design

Tags: php, mysql, performance, innodb, batch-processing

I have a scraper which visits many sites and finds upcoming events and another script which is actually supposed to put them in the database.  Currently the inserting into the database is my bottleneck and I need a faster way to batch the queries than what I have now.

What makes this tricky is that a single event has data across three tables which have keys to each other.  To insert a single event I insert the location or get the already existing id of that location, then insert the actual event text and other data or get the event id if it already exists (some are repeating weekly etc.), and finally insert the date with the location and event ids.

I can't use a REPLACE INTO because it will orphan older data with those same keys.  I asked about this in [Tricky MySQL Batch Query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8901683/tricky-mysql-batch-query) but if TLDR the outcome was I have to check which keys already exist, preallocate those that don't exist then make a single insert for each of the tables (i.e. do most of the work in php).  That's great but the problem is that if more than one batch was processing at a time, they could both choose to preallocate the same keys then overwrite each other.  Is there anyway around this because then I could go back to this solution?  The batches have to be able to work in parallel.

What I have right now is that I simply turn off the indexing for the duration of the batch and insert each of the events separately but I need something faster.  Any ideas would be helpful on this rather tricky problem. (The tables are InnoDB now... could transactions help solve any of this?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd recommend starting with [Mysql Lock Tables](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/lock-tables.html) which you can use to prevent other sessions from writing to the tables whilst you insert your data.

For example you might do something similar to this

```
mysql_connect("localhost","root","password");
mysql_select_db("EventsDB");
mysql_query("LOCK TABLE events WRITE");
$firstEntryIndex = mysql_insert_id() + 1;
/*Do stuff*/
...
mysql_query("UNLOCK TABLES);
```

The above does two things. Firstly it locks the table preventing other sessions from writing to it until you the point where you're finished and the unlock statement is run. The second thing is the $firstEntryIndex; which is the first key value which will be used in any subsequent insert queries.

Comment: Well, this would certainly solve the problem of data being able to overwrite each other but the whole goal is to make everything faster so limiting it to only one process at a time seems like a step back.

Comment: It's not limiting the process to a single instance, just making sure that you can process based on a single key without the risk of data loss/corruption. Which ever method you use it's not likely to provide the flexibility in pre-processing and security of lock tables without affecting efficiency.